# How to get the output plot

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, plot

I have a 3 dataframes for which I need the plot output. I am able to save the output but I need that It should pop up the output anytime the code runs.

```
plot = df.plot()
plot.legend(loc=2, prop={'size': 15})
plot.set_xlabel("Time", fontsize=20)
plot.set_ylabel("Force/Torque", fontsize=20)
plot.get_figure().savefig("xyz", dpi=200)
```

I tried using plot.show() but its giving an error.
Actually there is one main program when I am writing this piece of code I am getting the output pop up as well as the files were getting saved. But when I moved this code into another program and passing the dataframe from the main program then I am not getting the pop up output just the files are getting saved?

Comment: What error is it giving? I don't see any matplotlib etc. initialisation or setup...

Comment: If you just run just `plot = df.plot()` do you get a plot as output?

Comment: error ->        plot.get_figure().savefig('FrTq50mmCircleT3A_100'+"-all.png", dpi=200)
              -->  plot.show()     -->AttributeError: 'AxesSubplot' object has no attribute 'show'

Comment: @JuanC I am not getting pop up with plot= df.plot()

Comment: Could you post some sample data from your `df` ? Your figure is correctly saving, right? Where are you running python?

Comment: @JuanC one row of input is --> "0x0","1","4453511","-0.34659","0.445821","0.851698","-0.048046","0.122712","-0.057828","Feb 21, 2019 3:50:39:0 PM". I am running my Python on Canopy.

Comment: If you're running with <script>.py, you may want to include '#%%' at the beginner of your code. Finally, use 'plt.show()' to display a graph.